# Remove duplicates and sort from comma separated string in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a variable in XSLT called "Tags" which is a commas separated value.
eg
test,2013,2013,Buyers,Declutter,,2013,Fashion,,,Food,test,Kids,Fun,Media,Music,Sale,People,Music,Reuse,,2013,Twitter,Food

What is the best way to clean up this variable so there are no duplicates and it is sorted alphabetically.

I can combine this with a split function which is the next part of the work if this helps.

Thanks in advance

LMT

Comment: Best way? Don't use XSLT. This might help http://devspoint.wordpress.com/2011/04/29/split-multi-value-strings-using-xslt/ Personally I'd normalise the data before I used xslt on it

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?  What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT 2.0, this is pretty convenient:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0" xmlns:myfn="MY:FN" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:function name="myfn:sortCSV" as="xs:string*">
    <xsl:param name="csvString" as="xs:string"/>

    <!-- Split up string and remove duplicates -->
    <xsl:variable name="values" select="distinct-values(tokenize($csvString, '\s*,\s*'))" as="xs:string*"/>
    <!-- Return all elements, sorted -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$values">
      <xsl:sort/>
      <!-- We don't return empty strings -->
      <xsl:sequence select=".[.!='']"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Let's test our function -->
    <xsl:value-of select="myfn:sortCSV('x,b , c,, d,c  ,a,d')" separator=","/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With XSLT 1.0, you're pretty much out of luck. This kind of task would be much more complex.

Comment: Thanks - switched to c#